# Problems logging in to a webpage using java and jaunt-api

Tags: java, authentication, jaunt-api

So I'm trying to log in to a webpage using Jaunt. The first thing to mention is that the webpage is .aspx and the submit button has an option `onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoP..."` and as far as I know Jaunt doesn't support Javascript right?
In case I'm wrong, the code I'm using is the one in the examples of Jaunt:

```
Form form = userAgent.doc.getForm(0);
form.setTextField("Login1$UserName","USER");
form.setPassword("Login1$Password","PASSWORD");
form.setCheckBox("Login1$RememberMe",false);
form.submit("GO");
System.out.println(userAgent.getLocation());
```

All the names and values are correct, and the user and password works since I can log in using the web browser. After I execute the code, in the output I get this:

> message: UserAgent.sendPOST; Connection error requestUrl:
> http://webpagehere.com/default.aspx [posting
> __VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJLTk5MDc0NjQ2ZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAgURTG9naW4xJFJlbWVtYmVyTWUFF0xvZ2luMSRMb2dpbkltYWdlQnV0dG9upWcarODJIwpeMt8HCmfaBn6iMWI%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334&Login1%24UserName=USER&Login1%24Password=PASSWORD&Login1%24LoginButton=GO]
> response: [none]

The form div is this one:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1" style="text-align:center">
```

Any ideas what could be my problem? In case Jaunt doesn't allow me to do this login, could someone please recommend me a library for web scraping and interaction? Thanks!

Comment: Jsoup works well for this task. Just select the form, cast to a form element using ((FormElement) doc.select("form[name=form1]")).formData() and use the API to send the form. You can parse Jsoup with Jsoup.parse(html)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/asevans48/JScrape

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are stuck. Actually .aspx pages uses AJAX pagination. You will have to extract the values of __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and all other form values and then send them with POST method in the request body. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to get the request body which contains all these hidden variables and your entries to the form.

In Java you can use Selenium Or HTMLUnit which are Java GUI-Less browser, supporting JavaScript, to run agains web pages.

edit: You can use Jaunt-api as well, I just tried it with it, all you do is send a POST request alongwith the request-body, you can easily check it with Fiddler, and it works!!

Form values in HTTP POSTs are sent in the request body, in the same format as the querystring. You can find the request body of a link by inspecting it using the Fiddler and then  copy request body from Textview and send the encoded data as request body.

```
UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
userAgent.sendPOST("<your link to form page>","<request body>");
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear? What do yo mean by headers? Can you write the code to explain?

Comment: if still its not clear, send me a .aspx link and i will provide you the approach

Comment: Let's say facebook login page.

Comment: it uses a https, a secure channel, you cant just get the request message for it.. provide me a simple link that uses http connection.

Comment: You mean jaunt does not support it? Because i can log in (not on facebook another https login page) using standard java libraries. java.net.URL url = new URL(null, LOGIN_POST_PAGE, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());

Comment: jaunt supports it, its a GUI-Less browser so it will have all functionalities like a browser but you will have to do the extra work of indentifying the request body of the POST method and then modify it according to your use.